# Inline functions expansion with inner switch

Tags: c, inline

Consider the scenario where you have a complex procedure that have a state machine and is tracked with a state that never changes during a call to kernel, as in code illustrated below.

```
static inline void kernel(int recursion, int mode){
  if(!recursion) return;
  // branches all lead to similar switch cases here.
  // logical branches and loops can be quite complicated.
  switch(mode){
    default return;
    case 1: mode1(recursion-1);
    case 2: mode2(recursion-1);
  }
}
void mode1(int recursion){
  kernel(recursion,1)
}
void mode2(int recursion){
  kernel(recursion,2)
}
```

**If only `mode1` and `mode2` functions are called elsewhere, can recent compilers eliminate the inner branches?**

All functions are in the same compilation unit.

Came across this while implementing a interpreter for a subset of spirv byte code. The inner branch is for finding out how much to allocate, building up the AST, and doing the actual evaluation of expressions. The kernel takes care of traversing the tree, with all the switch on instruction OpCodes. Writing separate functions for each state will be even more difficult to maintain, since the kernel already takes up 1000+ loc, and moving up and down for the same traversal point and keeping them the same can be really difficult.

(I know modern c++ have constexpr if, but this is pure c code.)

Edit:
I've tried with msvc compiler with the following code:

```
uint32_t interp_code[]={1,2,1,1,2};

void mode1(const uint32_t* code, int recursion);
void mode2(const uint32_t* code, int recursion);

static INLINE void kernel(const uint32_t* code, int recursion, int mode)
{
    if (!recursion) return;
    // branches all lead to similar switch cases here.
    // logical branches and loops can be quite complicated.
    switch (*code) {
        default: return;
        case 1:
            switch (mode) {
                default: return;
                case 1: mode1(code + 1, recursion - 1);
                case 2: mode2(code + 1, recursion - 1);
            }
        case 2:
            switch(mode) {
                default: return;
                case 1: mode2(code + 1, recursion - 1);

                case 2: mode1(code + 1, recursion - 1);
            }
    }

}

void mode1(const uint32_t* code,int recursion)
{
    kernel(code, recursion, 1);
}
void mode2(const uint32_t* code, int recursion)
{
    kernel(code, recursion, 2);
}

int main()
{
    mode1(interp_code, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Using `inline` in the `INLINE` place yielded a function call (O2 optimizations), and using `__forceinline` yields the two modes compiled separately with no function call.

Disassembly for inline:

```
    31: void mode1(const uint32_t* code,int recursion)
    32: {
00007FF65F8910C0 48 83 EC 28          sub         rsp,28h  
    33:     kernel(code, recursion, 1);
00007FF65F8910C4 85 D2                test        edx,edx  
00007FF65F8910C6 74 6C                je          mode1+74h (07FF65F891134h)  
00007FF65F8910C8 48 89 5C 24 30       mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rbx  
00007FF65F8910CD 48 8D 59 04          lea         rbx,[rcx+4]  
00007FF65F8910D1 48 89 74 24 38       mov         qword ptr [rsp+38h],rsi  
00007FF65F8910D6 48 89 7C 24 20       mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],rdi  
00007FF65F8910DB 8D 7A FF             lea         edi,[rdx-1]  
00007FF65F8910DE 66 90                xchg        ax,ax  
00007FF65F8910E0 8B 4B FC             mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbx-4]  
00007FF65F8910E3 8B F7                mov         esi,edi  
00007FF65F8910E5 83 E9 01             sub         ecx,1  
00007FF65F8910E8 74 07                je          mode1+31h (07FF65F8910F1h)  
00007FF65F8910EA 83 F9 01             cmp         ecx,1  
00007FF65F8910ED 75 36                jne         mode1+65h (07FF65F891125h)  
00007FF65F8910EF EB 1A                jmp         mode1+4Bh (07FF65F89110Bh)  
00007FF65F8910F1 8B D7                mov         edx,edi  
00007FF65F8910F3 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF65F8910F6 E8 C5 FF FF FF       call        mode1 (07FF65F8910C0h)  
00007FF65F8910FB 41 B8 02 00 00 00    mov         r8d,2  
00007FF65F891101 8B D7                mov         edx,edi  
00007FF65F891103 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF65F891106 E8 F5 FE FF FF       call        kernel (07FF65F891000h)  
00007FF65F89110B 41 B8 02 00 00 00    mov         r8d,2  
00007FF65F891111 8B D7                mov         edx,edi  
00007FF65F891113 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF65F891116 E8 E5 FE FF FF       call        kernel (07FF65F891000h)  
00007FF65F89111B FF CF                dec         edi  
00007FF65F89111D 48 83 C3 04          add         rbx,4  
00007FF65F891121 85 F6                test        esi,esi  
00007FF65F891123 75 BB                jne         mode1+20h (07FF65F8910E0h)  
00007FF65F891125 48 8B 74 24 38       mov         rsi,qword ptr [rsp+38h]  
00007FF65F89112A 48 8B 5C 24 30       mov         rbx,qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
00007FF65F89112F 48 8B 7C 24 20       mov         rdi,qword ptr [rsp+20h]  
    34: }
00007FF65F891134 48 83 C4 28          add         rsp,28h  
00007FF65F891138 C3                   ret
```

For __forceinline:

```
    31: void mode1(const uint32_t* code,int recursion)
    32: {
00007FF670271002 EC                   in          al,dx  
00007FF670271003 28 85 D2 74 60 48    sub         byte ptr [rbp+486074D2h],al  
    33:     kernel(code, recursion, 1);
00007FF670271009 89 5C 24 30          mov         dword ptr [rsp+30h],ebx  
00007FF67027100D 48 8D 59 04          lea         rbx,[rcx+4]  
00007FF670271011 48 89 74 24 38       mov         qword ptr [rsp+38h],rsi  
00007FF670271016 48 89 7C 24 20       mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],rdi  
00007FF67027101B 8D 7A FF             lea         edi,[rdx-1]  
00007FF67027101E 66 90                xchg        ax,ax  
00007FF670271020 8B 4B FC             mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbx-4]  
00007FF670271023 8B F7                mov         esi,edi  
00007FF670271025 83 E9 01             sub         ecx,1  
00007FF670271028 74 07                je          mode1+31h (07FF670271031h)  
00007FF67027102A 83 F9 01             cmp         ecx,1  
00007FF67027102D 75 2A                jne         mode1+59h (07FF670271059h)  
00007FF67027102F EB 14                jmp         mode1+45h (07FF670271045h)  
00007FF670271031 8B D7                mov         edx,edi  
00007FF670271033 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF670271036 E8 C5 FF FF FF       call        mode1 (07FF670271000h)  
00007FF67027103B 8B D7                mov         edx,edi  
00007FF67027103D 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF670271040 E8 2B 00 00 00       call        mode2 (07FF670271070h)  
00007FF670271045 8B D7                mov         edx,edi  
00007FF670271047 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF67027104A E8 21 00 00 00       call        mode2 (07FF670271070h)  
00007FF67027104F FF CF                dec         edi  
00007FF670271051 48 83 C3 04          add         rbx,4  
00007FF670271055 85 F6                test        esi,esi  
00007FF670271057 75 C7                jne         mode1+20h (07FF670271020h)  
00007FF670271059 48 8B 74 24 38       mov         rsi,qword ptr [rsp+38h]  
00007FF67027105E 48 8B 5C 24 30       mov         rbx,qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
00007FF670271063 48 8B 7C 24 20       mov         rdi,qword ptr [rsp+20h]  
    34: }
00007FF670271068 48 83 C4 28          add         rsp,28h  
00007FF67027106C C3                   ret
```

It seems with `inline` the compiler chose to inline the entirety of `mode2` function body, and make `kernel` a separate function call. `__forceinline` forced the mode1 and mode2 to compile into two function bodies with the kernel. (This code doesn't break on the case, so fall through is expected)

Working with `inline` directive yields just the same code as nothing specified in `INLINE` in O2

Comment: What compilers did you try with what optimization options? What did your experiments reveal? If you want a theoretical, academic answer: Please ask some compilers' authors. -- A quick check with Clang and "-O3" produces empty functions for `mode1()` and `mode2()`. Your [mre] seems to be too minimal.

Comment: @thebusybee updated question with reproducible code and result from msvc compiler. It seems msvc compiler needs a force inline instead of normal inline to work. Other compilers not tested.

Comment: Clang does not inline if asked to not optimize, else generates only empty functions. Since no function has side effects, `main()` returns immediately.